# Using intensity of VV, VH, or combination of these for Sentinel-1 GRD

Tags: sentinel-1, sar

I have Sentinel-1 IW GRD images; for each capture date, one GeoTIFF with the VV and one with the VH values. I assume these are intensity values for the co-polarization and cross-polarization bands.
To perform image segmentation (estimating parcel boundaries), I was advised to use the SAR intensity values.

Should I use VV, VH, or a combination of these (maybe squared sum: VV^2 + VH^2)?

I have tried using both and their squared sum, but the resulting image segments do not correlate well with what I see on the S2 rgb-images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two intensities are indeed related to the polarization (V for vertical, H for horizontal; first letter for emission, second letter fo reception)I recommand you to use both and their ratio (not square sum), because it is the standard way to make rgb with Sentinel-1 data, which accounts for the polarization. This will however remain a challenging task because of the speckle, so if you have the opportunity to use Sentinel-2 images in you area this will be more efficient (of course, clouds will be a problem, then)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, to reproduce the RGB image, you'd use different values for the different RGB bands: 
Red: VV
Green: VH
Blue: VH - VV

There's a video worth watching on the subject by the [ESA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htme1WfRPh0):